# AngularJS $scope.$on() and $timeout()

Tags: angularjs

I am new to AngularJS. Please see the code below and tell me what it is doing.

```
$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function(event) {});
```

How to use it in a controller to access the DOM?

```
$timeout(function() { });
```

I am looking for explanation and example of how to use `$scope.$on()` and `$timeout()` in real life and what it does.

Comment: The DOM should not be accessed/manipulated from a controller. The only place for DOM access and manipulation is the `link` function in a `directive`.

Answer (score 4):

`$scope.$on` registers a listener for the event passed as the first parameter and executes the function passed as the second on each instance of said event. `$broadcast` and `$emit` can be used to send out custom events of your own.

`$timeout` can be used in place of `setTimeout` but when called with no delay argument will simply wait for the next digest before executing its callback function.

As for DOM manipulation, this should not be carried out in a standard 'jQuery like fashion'. If manipulation of the DOM is required a custom directive can be defined to encapsulate this functionality and therefore allow the Angular framework to govern its syncopation.

Comment: `$timeout` will run inside the Angular lifecycle. If you use the JS `setTimeout` instead you would need to call `$scope.digest()` manually.

Comment: i am new in ng...so still do not understand this `$scope.$on registers a listener for the event passed as the first parameter` would mind to explain it with small easy example. thanks